# HttpServletRequest#getParameter() takes more than 10 seconds to extract

Tags: tomcat, servlets

We are facing strange issue, while using HttpServletRequest.getParameter("SAMLResponse"). We have our application integrated with 3 different IDP OKTA, CAIMAN and SecureAuth. To extract SAML token from Http Request we are taking almost double the time to extract from OKTA. Yes token size is different in both cases.

1. OKTA token size is approx 7 KB and its taking 13-15 seconds to extract this token with above mentioned function.
2. Where as SecureAuth token is approx of double time 17KB and its taking approx. 44-47 seconds.

HttpServletRequet.getParameter("SAMLResponse") is very basic function of Servlet class. Why its taking so much time? Can we do any configuration in tomcat (related to POST request) or is there any other way to extract "SAMLResponse" token?

Comment: Parameters are parsed lazily upon the first call to `getParameter()`. The figures you cite in the question, are the total size of the POST or just the size of `SAMLResponse`? Are the parsing times **really** in seconds? I would say, they are in microseconds.

Comment: Yes I am talking about "SAMLResponse" token size and yes its in seconds. Thats why I am concerned. And as per my understanding I can only use HttpServletRequest.getParameter() function only. Or is there any other way?

Comment: That seems implausible, unless the JVM running Tomcat has an extremely low amount of memory or the system is swapping Tomcat. The time between the start of the SAML authentication procedure to its end can be measured in seconds, but only because of the human factor.

Comment: Still stuck to this unusual problem...although I had increased tomcat heap memory to 6gb

Answer (score 0):

you can try to configure socket.rxBufSize attribute 32k in Tomcat server and try

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).